# Does what you send in Scope Governs whether you can login with Microsoft Account using Azure AD V2 Endpoints

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have registered a application using the App Registration (Preview) Blade and added the Azure Service Management API as API Permissions I downloaded the MSAL based Sample from

https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2

Now in startup.auth.cs if i change the Scope i.e keep openid and add https://management.azure.com and then run and try and Login with a Microsoft Account i get the following error

This Doesn't Look like a Work or School Email you cant Sign-in here with Personal Account use your work or School Account Instead.

if i remove the Scope for https://managment.azure.com and just keep Openid profile offline_access i get the Consent Screen and Login

new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // The `Authority` represents the v2.0 endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
                    // The `Scope` describes the initial permissions that your app will need.  See https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-scopes/
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, "common", "/v2.0"),
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = "openid https://management.azure.com/.default",
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,

I am Expecting to have the user Login and Obtain a Token for management API , i am Looking for Reasons for getting the above Error is this Expected ? The Account that i am using exists in my directory as a Member . this works if i use a Managed user(user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com) to Login

Comment: You should probably use organizations instead of common. That allows only AAD accounts (like the v1 common endpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since personal MS accounts cannot be used to manage Azure subscriptions unless they are added to an Azure AD, you should use the `organizations` endpoint instead of `common`.

In v1 "common" meant any AAD tenant.
In v2 "common" means any AAD tenant + any personal MS account.
If you wanted only personal accounts, you can use "consumers".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document

You can use "organizations" to allow any AAD tenant but disallow MS accounts.
Of course a user can just edit the URL and login with a personal MS account anyway, so you'll want to check the tenant id of the logged in user.

The tenant id for MS accounts is always `9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad`, per the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims.
So check the `idp` claim.